# Probability of even sum in submatrices

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, finite-fields

There is a fixed integer $m\times n$ matrix $M$. The question is what is the probability that a random $m\times k$ submatrix summed over rows produce a column with all even numbers.

Without loss of generality assume that even numbers all equal 0, and odd numbers are ones. For a given $m\times k$ submatrix, for a given row, the probability that the sum is even equals the probability that the sum is odd. Then the probability that all $m$ rows are even equals $2^{-m}$ and does not depend on $k$.

I am puzzled with the fact that $m\times n$ matrix contains $n \choose k$ submatrices of shape $m\times k$. If I simply multiply $2^{-m}$ and $n \choose k$, for large enough $k$ it exceeds 1. As Mike Earnest pointed out, different $m\times k$ submatrices do not have to be independent. I don't clearly see a way to account for this. And the question now becomes, how many submatrices of shape $m\times k$ sum to column of zeros mod 2? Any hints and/or tips very much welcome.

The matrix $M$ is fixed. So we can extract any sort of information from it, $e.g.$ number of ones for the whole matrix, or for individual columns.

-edited for clarification, as requested in comments

Comment: You make it seems like we are given a _fixed_ integer matrix (call it $M$), and then you randomly select some columns. But then there is not enough info to answer, since the probability depends on $M$. For example, if $M$ happens to have all zeroes, then any sum is even, so the probability is one. Can you please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4563861/edit) to clarify?

Comment: Also, you cannot add the probabilities of events when the events are not disjoint, which explains why you are getting a probability greater than $1$.

Comment: For one single row, i.e.$m = 1$ case, you may count the number of odd and even numbers, then sum the hypergeometric pmf requiring that the number of odd numbers selected to be a even number. But for multiple rows, it seems that there is no obvious simplification to account for the relationship between them.

Comment: Since you are asking what the probability would be for _every_ potential matrix $M$, this question is way too broad. There would be no simple formula; the answer would have to be a computer program which took $M$ as input, and outputted the probability for that $M$. Knowing just the number of ones in $M$ is not enough info, the formula would be very complicated. Basically, I think this is too hard a problem to expect an answer on MSE.

Comment: So far I can prove that for $k> rank M$, if submatrix does not contain other submatrices summing to zero column, this probability equals zero